# CertUtil: ERROR_INVALID_ACL (0x80070538) exception when trying to install root certificate on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, exceptions, certutil

I have a program that installs a certificate to Trusted Root (with user's consent). However, some of the users are unable to use my software due to an exception that occures whenever a command to add a certificate is executed. It happens both when using certutil and powershell.

---

### Certutil

Command: `-addstore -user -f root cert.pem`

Output: `-addstore команда НЕ ВЫПОЛНЕНА: 0x80070538 (WIN32: 1336 ERROR_INVALID_ACL)
Список управления доступом (ACL) имеет неверную структуру.`

Roughly translates to `The access control list structure is invalid`.

---

### PowerShell

Command: `Import-Certificate -FilePath .\cert.pem -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root`

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvA8g.jpg

---

Unfortunately there's not much about that error on the Internet so in case anyone has had experience with it I'd be greatful if you share.

Comment: Try this command : `CERTUTIL -addstore -enterprise -f -v root "cert.pem"`

Comment: @harrymc, sorry for the delay, I had to wait until one of the users with this problem got in contact with me. Executing this command indeed fixed the issue. Could you please explain why this is the case? Is it security-related (i.e. some antivirus software interfering)?

Comment: You were just using the wrong parameters, so I added an answer about that.

Comment: @harrymc actually, `-user` installs a certificate only to a current user's profile and `-enterprise` installs it machine-wise. When installing a certificate machine-wise it is required to run certutil elevated, while the first option doesn't have this requirement. Nevertheless, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct parameters for the certutil command are:

```
CERTUTIL -addstore -enterprise -f -v root "cert.pem"
```